# ajax posting data & sign truncate issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to pass the ampersand '&' sign in text via ajax to php file.

I used encodeURIComponent() like this:

```
url: "add_process.php",
data: "title="+ encodeURIComponent(title) +"& stages="+ values1,
success: function(html){
```

but when I execute this, all data after the ampersand '&' gets truncated and doesn't get saved in database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the space you have here:

```
"& stages="
```

like this:

```
"&stages="
```